# Overall total from du command

Tags: grep, rhel, ls, du

I am trying to find out all directories and the overall size starting with pattern `int-*`

For this I am using the below command

```
  $sudo ls -ld int-* | grep ^d | wc -l
  3339

  $ sudo ls -ld int-* | grep ^d | du -sh
  204G    .
```

Are my commands correct ? Any other command combination to gather the above information ?

Comment: I use du -shc <filespec> .. the 'c' gives you a grand total.

Answer (score 4):

Simply `du -shc ./int-*/` should give the grand total of all directories under the pattern `int-*`. Add a trailing slash would do the trick for directories

AS

-s, report only the sum of the usage in the current directory, not for each directory therein contained

-h, is to obtain the results in human readable format

Comment: The above command will consider all files along with directories  .  I want only for directories with pattern int-*

Comment: @ZamaQues Got the point. Amended the answer to suit your needs. Let me know if that helps

Comment: I think we also have to use -c option , otherwise it gives the size of individual directories only

Comment: Agree. You have to include -c. In that sense, your second snippet is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

No, your commands are not *okay* (though the first is not outright wrong).

Both parse the output of `ls` which a dangerous thing to do as `ls` is supposed to produce human-readable output and the format might change in the future (and indeed it has several times over the years, and it differs across various Unix flavors).  So generally, parsing the output `ls` is considered bad.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for details.

The second command also pipes this output into `du` while `du` isn't reading anything from `stdin`.  It just ignores this kind of input and will do the same as it would have done if being called without the pipe: `du -sh`.  This of course is not what you intended.

What you wanted can best be achieved in a proper fashion like this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'int-*' -printf 'x\n' | wc -l
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'int-*' -print0 | du --files0-from=- -c
```

Using the option `--files0-from=-` the command `du` *does* read NUL-separated file names from `stdin`.  `-c` makes it print a total of all arguments.

Of course you can still add options `-h` for human-readable sizes (4G etc.) and `-s` if you do not want sizes for the subdirectories of your arguments.

If you want *only* the grand total, the best way is to chomp the output by piping it into `tail -1`.